# Как вычислить координату высоты view относительно экрана, или корневого layout в Android?

Tags: android, view, position, координаты

Ситуация следующая: у меня есть layout, в котором есть еще один layout, который вращается по нажатию кнопки. В этом вращающемся layout есть 8 view, расположенных по кругу. Задача – вычислить самый верхний view после вращения. То есть после вращения позиции view изменяются, и нужно найти тот который выше всех.

Я пробовал различные вариации взятия координаты Y, но они либо совсем не те, либо возвращают позицию относительно родительского layout, а не относительно положения на экране или на корневом layout.

`getLocationInWindow()` и `getLocationOnScreen()` уже пробовал – не помогают

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLocationOnScreen()` всё таки решил задачу. Проблема была в методе осуществления анимации. `RotateAnimation` был использован как первый попавшийся вариант, что и сыграло злую шутку. Этот способ не зря считается устаревшим. Он изменяет положение view только визуально, но физически координаты не менялись.

Кому интересно, реализовывалась простая игра типа "Колесо фортуны", где поиск выпавшего результата производится через поиск наивысшего TextView, расположенного на "колесе". Реализация довольно костыльная и простенькая, но она такой и задумывалась.